# The procedure entry point could not be located?

Tags: c++, sfml

For some odd reason when I try to render a simple window in SFML, I get a strange error when using Visual C++ 2010: `The procedure entry point ??()VideoMode@sf@@QAE@III@Z could not be located in the dynamic link library sfml-window.dll`

When using Code::Blocks I get no error at all. But the problem seems to be the same.

However the point is I still get no SFML application window, or a "fixed" window as I like to call it.

What's my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that I had to statically link the libraries.

Thank for your answers though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the DLLs that are being loaded, do not match the lib files that you are linking with.

I have resolved similar problems by recompiling the DLL's under the same compiler and settings as the executable project

Comment: This could indeed be the problem. I have SFML for Visual Studio and SFML for MinGW, I'm gonna reinstall one or the other IDE so I don't get this mixed up. This has happened one too many times in the past to be tolerable. Like seriously :(

Answer (score -1):

You're not linking all the libraries. Code::Blocks link all of 'em automatically, but not VS. When i create applications using OpenGL, i do this (linking via code, doesn't looks pretty, but "just works"):

```
#pragma comment(lib, "sfml-system.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "sfml-window-s.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "sfml-graphics.lib")
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. I've linked them all properly and even specified the directories even though it is not needed.

Comment: -1 he doesn't report a linker error; instead a failure after/during startup

Comment: sfml-window-s contains some functions sfml-window does not. Though i know what i'm talking about